# Documentation of posix_acl_access and friends?

Tags: linux, posix

I am trying to figure out how to get/set file access information through getxattr of "system.posix_acl_access". Suprisingly, a Google search resulted in no such link in the first pages. The man pages mention the attributes, but give no details beyond saying they are standard.

Assuming I wish to actually use them, is there any better option than reading the source for coreutils? I'm wondering what other attributes, under system or otherwise, I might be missing this way.

**Edited to add:**
The ACLs themselves are documented in POSIX 1003.1e (available for download [here](http://wt.tuxomania.net/publications/posix.1e/download.html). It is an abandoned standard, but as Linux implements it, and coreutils (in particular, cp) uses it (at least the way it is compiled on Ubuntu), then it is relevent, standard or not.

This question, however, relates not to the particular entry, but for an extensive list of all standard extended attributes (though it seems, from reading sources, that on Linux only system.posix_acl_access and system.posix_acl_default exist).

Comment: Notice that Linux' ACLs never became part of POSIX for a reason I forgot.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Linux implements it, and coreutils uses it (at least, the version compiled for Debian and Ubuntu). As such, standard or not, it's still relevent.